# Is the size of an iterator positive correlation with the size of its container?

Tags: c++

For example, is `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator` bigger than `std::vector<int>::iterator`?

Comment: What do you mean by size? The space occupied by `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is not necessarily more than the space occupied by `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, I mean the space occupied by them.

Comment: could be formal and talk about `sizeof` operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions of standard library iterator types (and hence their sizes) are implementation-defined. It is possible that `sizeof(vector<T>::iterator)` depends on `T`. However, in practice, this tends not to be the case. `vector<T>::iterator` in practice is just a wrapper over `T*`. Likewise, `list<T>::iterator` is typically a wrapper over a pointer to a node of the list. Some types, such as deques, may have more complicated iterators, but the size is still unlikely to depend on the template parameter.

(Edit: for `std::array` the iterator *is* a pointer.)

Comment: `std::vector<bool>::iterator` could well be a different size than normal due to weird specialization of `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh yeah, I forgot about that.

Comment: In debug mode with VS2013, the `vector`/`list<int>::iterator`s are as large as 3 pointers; the *"just wrappers over `T*`"* assertion is right for "release" builds though....

Answer (score 2):

Since it's entirely implementation defined anyway, you might as well just do a quick test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

int main() { 
    std::cout << "vector<vector<int>>::iterator: " << sizeof(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator) << "\n";
    std::cout << "vector<int>::iterator: " << sizeof(std::vector<int>::iterator) << "\n";
    std::cout << "vector<bool>:iterator: " << sizeof(std::vector<bool>::iterator) << "\n";
    std::cout << "deque<int>::iterator: " << sizeof(std::deque<int>::iterator) << "\n";
    std::cout << "list<int>::iterator: " << sizeof(std::list<int>::iterator) << "\n";
    std::cout << "list<list<int>>::iterator: " << sizeof(std::list<std::list<int>>::iterator) << "\n";
    std::cout << "deque<list<int>>::iterator: " << sizeof(std::deque<std::list<int>>::iterator) << "\n";
}
```

Results: (VC++ 2015):

```
vector<vector<int>>::iterator: 8
vector<int>::iterator: 8
vector<bool>:iterator: 16
deque<int>::iterator: 24
list<int>::iterator: 8
list<list<int>>::iterator: 8
deque<list<int>>::iterator: 24
```

...and with g++ 5.1:

```
vector<vector<int>>::iterator: 8
vector<int>::iterator: 8
vector<bool>:iterator: 16
deque<int>::iterator: 32
list<int>::iterator: 8
list<list<int>>::iterator: 8
deque<list<int>>::iterator: 32
```

Comment: 64 bits mode? Might be useful to add `sizeof(void*)` to the list.